# What IP address to use on client-side using socket.io for production?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, client-server, real-time

The code that I am using right now is :

```
    <!--Socket.io -->
    <script src='http://172.16.17.185:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
```

Where, 172.16.17.185 is the IP address on our LAN on which my server runs and port 3000 is used for socket.io communication.

The examples on the socket.io website use localhost in place of the server IP address. I started with this. Using localhost, my page loaded fine on the server, but no other PC on the LAN was able to create the socket object (as it was trying to look for socket.io on its localhost, which wasnt there).

So, I changed localhost to the IP address of the server, and everything worked fine.

Until, I tried accessing it from outside. Since this IP address is valid only on the LAN, it doesnt work like it should on the internet.

Is there a workaround for this problem ? or do I need to find the public IP of the server and use it ? Does this create any security vulnerabilities for the server as I dont have authorization ?

So far: http://www.ipsacademy.org/weather

Server code in [web-server.js](https://github.com/chintanp/weather_station/blob/master/angulared/web_server.js)

Comment: you have page and socket.io set up on different node.js servers?

Comment: You have page hosting set up very weirdly. Couldn't you use normal http build in node.js. From what I can remember you most likely what socket.io websocket on the same connection as http page.

Comment: @Kubuxu : No, I dont think so, I have only one nodejs server. It serves files on the port 8000, using a standard http server as provided by angularjs seed and socket.io connection happens on the port 3000

Comment: I always used socket.io as expansion of regular http so you can use relative links.

Comment: @Kubuxu : I dont understand what you mean by "page hosting setup weirdly". This is my first live website, and I think I also need to work on routing the page request, and some other stuff, but right now, I want to focus on getting the data.

Comment: You should use http server created in line 45 to serve content or other way around, use content serving server for socket.io. Then you can use relative address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the socket.io server from outside you LAN, you **must** use public IP (and possibly avoid the use of port 3000).

In a production environment you must use a fronted proxy (like nginx) to translate requests to your socket.io server to the private LAN address.

Following example in the [nginx blog](http://nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) you can use something like this:

```
location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_pass http://172.16.17.185:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";    
}
```

This will not cause any security problem different from any publicly accessible service on Internet.

Comment: I found my public ip from google etc. and replaced the LAN IP with the public ip with out any other changes, but it doesnt work now, not even in my LAN. I am guessing this is because the public ip is the one that is of the router provided by the ISP and not necessarily of the machine on which my server is running, so it doesnt have access to the socket, although the error is different from the last time. **The connection times out.**

Comment: Is there a way I can access the socket data outside of the LAN, without using nginx, as I think nginx would increase the complexity of my project.

Comment: It depends on your router. Normally they give the ability to do something like: all the TCP (and/or UDP) traffic on PUBLIC_IP:EXTERNAL_SPECIFIC_PORT will be redirected to INTERNAL_IP:INTERNAL_SPECIFIC_PORT. If your router can do this, you'll solve a part of your problem: you'll access to your internal server from the outside of your LAN on (i.e.) port 3000.

Comment: Right now, the PUBLIC_IP:8000 is mapped to  INTERNAL_IP:8000 for serving the files. I should try to P_IP:3000 to I_IP:3000, so the code should work.

Comment: Yes if you configure your router it should work, but you are still missing a point: 3000 is a non privileged port that sometimes is filtered out by firewall and/or routers. This means that you'll never be sure that everyone from outside your LAN will reach your server.

Comment: Thanks, the public IP works, still to introduce nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code you are using separate http instances for serving page and socket.io. If you change that to use the same http server you can use relative URL for socket.io connection.

Comment: Although I didnt understand, all of it, the network admin did forward the port and it is live and accessible currently from the outside.[http://www.ipsacademy.org/weather](http://www.ipsacademy.org/weather). You will see some port forwarding in action here.

Comment: But it doesnt, ideally, the wait for it, should become invisible in a few secs and the table should get populated with livedata and keep updating every second. If you go to developer tools console, you would see and error, failed to load resource, which the actual problem.

Comment: @ChintanPathak I can't help you as I on a phone. No debug tools unfortunately.

Comment: @ChintanPathak agh, I see the issue now.

Comment: thanks, re-wrote to make all communication happen on the port 8000.